# Protecting Myself From Bullying When the Manager Abuses Their Minority Status To Cover Bullying

Tags: careers, bullying

I am facing with animosity, bullying, and targeted harassment from my manager. Although there is evidence, the upper management keeps silent.

My manager abuses their minority status as a cover. My organization, as well as I, give unrestrained support for inclusion and diversity. If it makes any difference, I have been actively supporting equal rights and protesting for the rights of minorities my entire life.

What are the organizations I should ask for help?

---

Unfortunately, I cannot disclose details here as I fear retaliation.

Comment: Please add your location and (if at all relevant) if you are a member of a union.

Comment: @Hilmar answer-material right there

Comment: Who is doing the bullying? What is the nature of the bullying? What difference does it make to the situation that your manager is a minority? Edit this information into the question.

Comment: The way you talk might be the source of the hostility from your manager. It’s unprofessional and honestly and in todays society completely unacceptable even outside of work. Of course the way you describe your manager honestly was never actually acceptable even 70 years ago.

Comment: @yujaiyu please don't do that to the post. I don't see how you could face retaliation, your profile doesn't disclose personal data. At this point you already got answers and at least one has positive score (meaning you can't delete it as you found out). What we can do is disassociate your name/profile from the post if you want to... if yes, please flag for mod requesting so and we'll handle it... I rolled back the changes to the previous, not vandalized post.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I mean this particular minority group. Other minority groups receive less attention, unfortunately.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I flagged the post for moderation and requested you to disassociate this question from my profile. I am honestly afraid of severe retaliation. Why did you remove my comment? Why are you insisting on putting me in the risk of retaliation?

Comment: @yujaiyu I reckon that you may be anxious, but please calm down. If you see carefully, you'll see that I resolved the flag and wrote you a comment indicating I escalated such request (mods can't disassociate). I'm also cleaning comments that are no longer useful and to avoid unnecessary attention to your request... what's left is to wait for your request to be processed...

Comment: @DarkCygnus Sorry for panicking but I am really afraid.

Comment: @yujaiyu I sympathize with you, It's gonna be fine... and can't help thinking that if you feel that way about your company and this situation, I wonder if that's the right place for you to be...

Comment: Talk to HR if you haven't done so. We frequently say "HR is not your friend" but they are not your enemy either. Make sure you say the magic words "hostile workplace" and "bullying". Uncontrolled workplace bullying is a lawsuit waiting to happen, and one of HRs jobs is to prevent the company from being sued.

Answer (score 4):

Generally if your manager is bullying you and has the hierarchies support or they turn a blind eye your best option is to job hunt and find a better working situation elsewhere.

You can as others suggest document and hope to eventually get some action on your behalf, but this probably won't end well. You can win some protection and still be in a hostile workplace. It's better to save the grief and leave altogether.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a tad confused as to how the mentioning of your manager's minority group association is relevant to the question. There may be details which I'm missing, but I would say that any form of bullying from any party in a professional setting should be addressed with your HR department.

Like others have stated, documenting the bullying is a great way for you to provide evidence towards your issue and will help solve the problem.

Have you attempted to address those who are bullying you directly? Any and all suggestions being made are done so without full context to your specific situation, but there are times when directly confronting those who are mistreating you is the best solution.

Pulling someone aside and having a one on one discussion about the unwarranted behavior's could prevent the issue from escalating further.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is much like Hilmar's comment:

Document. Document. Document.

BCC Emails to a private/non-work account.
Make audio recordings on your phone.
Talk to co-workers who bore witness to any incidents.

Now - if there are special privileges being afforded to this person on the grounds of their minority status, make sure you document more than you think you need.

Comment: The legality of recorded audio is going depend on location

Comment: @peterm: Yep. Immediate dated transcription if your memory of the fall may be the best you can do, legally.